# format date when posting to server in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using ionic1 and angularjs1 in a project.

This is a module where a user have to search between periods to get results. The date format of server returns like this: `2017-02-28T00:00:00Z`, the post from the client side textbox when I echo in `php` is also like this:  `2017-06-10T07:00:00.000Z`

Now my issue is how do I format the date in the post to send like this `2017-02-28T00:00:00Z` so it matches with the server

javascript code:

```
$http.post("http://localhost:8080/server_scripts/bills.php",{'sdate':$scope.sdate}).success(function(data){});
```

Comment: Have you tried to search? There a dozens of questions/answers related to date formating.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject $filter service in your code then you use it like this

```
$filter('date')($scope.sdate, "yyyy-MM-dd", "UTC");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.